# How to calculate the different of two time? one in firebase , one is current time

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to calculate the different between time, but I have no idea how to do it. First I get the current after that I retrieve the time from the database. I don't know how to create an equation to calculate both of them.

```js
//get the time
h = now.getHours();
m = now.getMinutes();
if (h < 10)
    h = '0' + h;
if (m < 10)
    m = '0' + m;
var timestring = h + ":" + m;


var query = firebaseRef.orderByChild('carplate').equalTo(carplate);

query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        var time = child.val().time;

        var diff = timestring - time; //how to calculate the different

    })
});
```

[image: My Database]

Answer (score 1):

Store the time as a UTC Timestamp using `Date.now()`. Simply subtract the lesser from the greater to get the difference. Format out the time to human readable only for UI purposes.

https://rack.pub/timestamp

Comment: but how to store the time in firebase as a UTC timestamp?

Comment: @Ron You can also use [server timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue) from firebase.

Comment: @ShiHangNg You make the timestamp a value. For example `createdOn: Date.now()` then `.set` that to a node/document in Firebase/Firestore.